# recommender - recommendation reasoning (get similarities )

Tags: r, recommender-system, similarities

I’m using recommenderlab to build a UBCF and produce recommendations. The process seems to be ok, and the predictions are making sense. Now,what I need to have, is the reasoning for each prediction, i.e., which users are being considered neighbors of a specific user.

My sample code is:

```
library(recommenderlab) 
data(Jester5k) 

r <- sample(Jester5k, 1000)

rec_ub <- Recommender(r[1:100],method="UBCF", param=list(normalize = "Z-score",method="Cosine", nn=3,minRating=1))
recom_ub <- predict(rec_ub, Jester5k[1001:1002], n=20, type="ratings")

my.df<-as(recom_ub,"matrix")
rownames(my.df)<- rownames(Jester5k[1001:1002])

my.result<-melt(my.df, id = 1)
names(my.result)<-c("user","item","value")
my.result<-my.result[order(my.result$user,-my.result$value),]
my.result<-subset(my.result,value>0)
```

For instance , I need to know why the item j76 is being recommended to user u11691 ,i.e, which users are actually the neighbors of that user .

I'll appreciate some help.